# Forçar um script shell ser executado no terminal

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

> O usuário irá baixar o script de um site interno e executá-lo. O que eu queria era que após o download o usuário dê dois clicks no script e ele seja executado e não aberto para edição.

Existe um jeito de forçar a abertura de um `script shell` no terminal pela interface gráfica?

Quando clico duas vezes no `.sh` ou `.run` ele abre no editor de texto.
 
Se renomeio para `.bin` ele diz que não sabe o que fazer e pede para procurar na central de programas.

Até já compilei com o `shc` para ver se executava mas não funcionou.
Ideias?

Comment: Não sei se entendi muito bem, me parece que você quer criar uma especie de atalho para seu `.sh`, talvez esse link te ajude [vivaolinux.com.br](https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/dica/Criando-atalhos-(arquivos-*.desktop)-manualmente-no-KDE-Gnome-e-XFCE)

Comment: Depende da distribuição Linux que está usando, depende de você definir a *hash bang* corretamente, depende de você dar permissão de execução no computador após baixado o arquivo. Se quer algo executável, é mais fácil criar um do que tentar executar magicamente um *script*. De qualquer forma o problema não parece ser de programação e provavelmente a pergunta será fechada.

Comment: Uso o Debian Stretch porém o script será usado em micros com Ubuntu 16.04 ou 18.04. Costumo usar #!/bin/sh mas testei com bash também e deu no mesmo. Testei em um micro com ubuntu 16.04 e após o download o script já está com permissão de execução. Não estou pedindo mágica alguma, só pergunto se há a possibilidade.

Answer (score 1):

Dependendo da interface gráfica, clicando com o botão direito e indo em propriedades você pode direcionar para com o que você quer abrir por default, semelhante ao que existe no Windows também.

Comment: Sim mas nesse caso ainda teria que pedir para o usuário fazer algo além de dois cliques. A ideia é que o usuário não faça nada além de dois cliques.